# Is there anything in the works with html5/javascript to prevent opening the same web-app in more than one browser instance?

Tags: javascript, html

Okay so it's sorta pointless considering that even if there was support for this you could still open more than one instance if you have more than one browser installed, but I was wondering anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to emphasize what others have said, No.  This is entirely a server-side problem.

Answer (score 2):

I hope not. This restriction would be a pain to users and only underline a problem in the Web Application Infrastructure.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript and HTML are rendered and run within the browser and have no control over the browser itself.  It would be quite dangerous to give them the ability to manipulate and restrict the behavior of the browser.

What are you trying to achieve by restricting them?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a webapp they need to log into I would just restrict a user from being logged in more than once at a time. Other than that would wouldn't want to restrict their opening of the actual window